# Redmine, interlan error when going to "My account"

Tags: heroku, redmine

I install Redmine on Heroku host, after solving some erorrs with gems, everything seems to be working. Except one small thing, when i click "My account", there is "internal error" with code 500.

I didn't see anything interesting in logs. Redmine was installed from windows 7 machine. If you can, pleas write reply easy to understand for newbie, or even step by step instruction. It's my totally first time doing something on server, and I need everything working for tomorrow. Thanks in advance.

Logs from heroku log console. Is there any other?

```
    2016-07-19T17:27:28.502527+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/my/account" for 81.190.76.211 at 2016-07-19 17:27:28 +0000

2016-07-19T17:27:28.511962+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MyController#account as HTML
2016-07-19T17:27:28.535131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/my/account" host=rgredmine.herokuapp.com request_id=b3eb89ba-2a4b-46d1-949a-b5d24f7b266f fwd="81.190.76.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=43ms status=500 bytes=968
```

Comment: Could you post any more logs? Does it work locally? Have you run all migrations with heroku run rake db:migrate ?

Comment: It's everything which was printed on heroku site in "View logs". I don't try this locally, just follow tutorial  http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_(%3E_25x)_on_Heroku 
and using SO to solve encountered problems. Generally, i don't really know what i have just done. I think that all migrations was ran properly.